# PlSQL dynamic query to pivot data on timestamps

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a dynamic SQL query to see the Dates in columns, The Dates row will keep on adding everyday, so the query has to be dynamic.
I want some columns to be in rows and some rows has to be columns, Pivot function will work, but i need some help to create this query.

***Data:-***

```
 PLANNER_ID|ASSIGNED|TODO|DONE|REJECTED|BLOCKING_PROJECTS|AVERAGE|WORKING_DAYS|DATES
 Planner 1 |25      |0   |0   |0       |0                |0%     |1           |2018.11.26
 Planner 1 |18      |0   |0   |0       |0                |0%     |1           |2018.11.21
 Planner 1 |26      |0   |0   |0       |0                |0%     |1           |2018.11.25
 Planner 1 |25      |0   |0   |0       |0                |0%     |1           |2018.11.28
 Planner 1 |25      |0   |0   |0       |0                |0%     |1           |2018.11.27
 Planner 1 |26      |0   |0   |0       |0                |0%     |1           |2018.11.24
 Planner 1 |25      |0   |0   |0       |0                |0%     |1           |2018.11.29
```

***Output needed as:-***

```
  PLANNER_ID|PROJECTS          |21-NOV-2018|24-NOV-2018|25-NOV-2018|26-NOV-2018|27-NOV-2018|28-NOV-2018|29-NOV-2018
  Planner 1 |ASSIGNED          |0          |0          |0          |0          |0          |0          |0
  Planner 1 |TODO              |0          |0          |0          |0          |0          |0          |0
  Planner 1 |AVERAGE           |0%         |0%         |0%         |0%         |0%         |0%         |0%
  Planner 1 |BLOCKING_PROJECTS |0          |0          |0          |0          |0          |0          |0
  Planner 1 |DONE              |0          |0          |0          |0          |0          |0          |0
  Planner 1 |REJECTED          |0          |0          |0          |0          |0          |0          |0
  Planner 1 |WORKING_DAYS      |1          |1          |1          |1          |1          |1          |1
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example query.

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT *
    FROM (
           SELECT 'Planner 2' AS planner_id, '15' AS assigned, '10' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '26%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.26' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 2' AS planner_id, '18' AS assigned, '12' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '21%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.21' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 2' AS planner_id, '16' AS assigned, '13' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '25%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.25' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 2' AS planner_id, '15' AS assigned, '14' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '28%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.28' AS dates FROM dual 
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '25' AS assigned, '1' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '26%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.26' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '28' AS assigned, '2' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '21%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.21' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '26' AS assigned, '3' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '25%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.25' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '25' AS assigned, '4' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '28%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.28' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '25' AS assigned, '5' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '27%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.27' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '26' AS assigned, '6' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '24%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.24' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '25' AS assigned, '7' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '29%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.29' AS dates FROM dual 
         )
)
SELECT *
  FROM (
         SELECT  planner_id, projects, dates, quantity
           FROM t
        UNPIVOT (quantity FOR projects IN (assigned AS 'ASSIGNED', todo AS 'TODO', done AS 'DONE', rejected AS 'REJECTED', blocking AS 'BLOCKING', average AS 'AVERAGE', working_days AS 'WORKING_DAYS'))
       )
 PIVOT  (MAX(quantity) FOR (dates) IN ('2018.11.26'  AS "2018.11.26" , '2018.11.21'  AS "2018.11.21" , '2018.11.25'  AS "2018.11.25" , '2018.11.28'  AS "2018.11.28" , '2018.11.27'  AS "2018.11.27" , '2018.11.24'  AS "2018.11.24" , '2018.11.29' AS "2018.11.29"))
ORDER BY planner_id, projects;
```

If list of values in DATES column is not constant or is huge then you have to generate this query in dynamic way. You have to generate list of dates for PIVOT

```
DECLARE
  lv_query CLOB :=
q'[WITH t AS (
  SELECT *
    FROM (
           SELECT 'Planner 2' AS planner_id, '15' AS assigned, '10' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '26%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.26' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 2' AS planner_id, '18' AS assigned, '12' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '21%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.21' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 2' AS planner_id, '16' AS assigned, '13' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '25%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.25' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 2' AS planner_id, '15' AS assigned, '14' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '28%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.28' AS dates FROM dual 
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '25' AS assigned, '1' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '26%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.26' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '28' AS assigned, '2' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '21%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.21' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '26' AS assigned, '3' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '25%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.25' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '25' AS assigned, '4' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '28%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.28' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '25' AS assigned, '5' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '27%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.27' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '26' AS assigned, '6' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '24%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.24' AS dates FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Planner 1' AS planner_id, '25' AS assigned, '7' AS todo, '0' AS done, '0' AS rejected, '0' AS blocking, '29%' AS average, '1' AS working_days, '2018.11.29' AS dates FROM dual 
         )
)
SELECT *
  FROM (
         SELECT  planner_id, projects, dates, quantity
           FROM t
        UNPIVOT (quantity FOR projects IN (assigned AS 'ASSIGNED', todo AS 'TODO', done AS 'DONE', rejected AS 'REJECTED', blocking AS 'BLOCKING', average AS 'AVERAGE', working_days AS 'WORKING_DAYS'))
       )
 PIVOT  (MAX(quantity) FOR (dates) IN (#PivotDates))
ORDER BY planner_id, projects]';

  /*
  *  Generate list of dates for PIVOT
  */
  FUNCTION pivotDates
  RETURN CLOB
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN yourPivotDates;
  END pivotDates;
BEGIN

  lv_query := REPLACE(lv_query, '#PivotDates', pivotDates());

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_query;
END;
/
```